# Why does this result in deadlock?

Tags: go, channel

I can't understand why the following code resulting in deadlock...anyone can help me?

In what conditions, channel will go into deadlock? I am really confused...

The following code is to print letters and numbers in this order
"12AB34CD56EF78GH910IJ1112KL1314MN1516OP1718QR1920ST2122UV2324WX2526YZ2728"
I want use channel to achieve this goal, but got deadlock.
when removing numberDone channel, it goes OK.

````
import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    AlterPrint()
}

// POINT: communicate between goroutines by channel

func AlterPrint(){
  letter, number := make(chan bool), make(chan bool)
  letterDone := make(chan bool)
  numberDone := make(chan bool)
  go func() {
    i := 1
    for {
      if i > 28 {
          numberDone <- true
          return
      }
      select{
        case <-number: {
          fmt.Print(i)
          i++
          fmt.Print(i)
          i++
          letter <- true
          break
        }
        default: {
          break
        }
      }

    }
  }()

  go func(){
    i := 'A'
    for {
      if i > 'Z' {
        letterDone <- true
        return
      }
      select{
        case <-letter: {
          fmt.Print(string(i))
          i++
          fmt.Print(string(i))
          i++
          number <- true
          break
        }
        default: {
          break
        }
      }
    }
  }()
  number <- true
  <- letterDone
  <- numberDone
}```

I expect the output of "12AB34CD56EF78GH910IJ1112KL1314MN1516OP1718QR1920ST2122UV2324WX2526YZ2728", 
but the actual output is 
goroutine 1 [chan receive]:
main.AlterPrint()
    /tmp/54841538.go:66 +0x183
main.main()
    /tmp/54841538.go:7 +0x14

goroutine 5 [chan send]:
main.AlterPrint.func1(0xc82000c240, 0xc82000c180, 0xc82000c120)
    /tmp/54841538.go:31 +0x25a
created by main.AlterPrint
    /tmp/54841538.go:40 +0xde
exit status 2
````

Comment: Sorry that I miss some error information. The the actual output is:      12AB34CD56EF78GH910IJ1112KL1314MN1516OP1718QR1920ST2122UV2324WX2526YZ2728fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!
goroutine 1 [chan receive]:
main.AlterPrint()
    /home/runner/alter_print.go:62 +0x157
main.main()
    /home/runner/main.go:4 +0x20

goroutine 18 [chan send]:
main.AlterPrint.func1(0xc000074180, 0xc0000740c0, 0xc000074060)
    /home/runner/alter_print.go:27 +0x148
created by main.AlterPrint
    /home/runner/alter_print.go:14 +0xd9
exit status 2

Answer (score -1):

It should actually print what you expected and then deadlock. The second goroutine finishes everything, sends letterdone and terminates. At that point, main starts waiting at numberdone. The first goroutine prints the last two numbers, and starts waiting at letter<-true. That's the deadlock, at this point nothing can move forward.
Try using fmt.Println instead of Print, maybe because of buffering it is not printing everything.

Comment: I don't think this is true. The first thing both goroutines try to do is send on an unbuffered channel, which is a blocking operation and will halt both goroutines. After spawning the goroutines, main also attempts to send on an unbuffered channel that nothing is reading from, so no action can possibly happen.

Comment: The first goroutine will try to read from <-number. The second goroutine will try to read from <-letter. They will both busy-wait trying to read from these channels until main goroutine writes on number. Why do you think the first thing they'll do is write? They won't write unless they read first.

Comment: Sorry that I miss some error information. The the actual output is:      12AB34CD56EF78GH910IJ1112KL1314MN1516OP1718QR1920ST2122UV2324WX2526YZ2728fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!
goroutine 1 [chan receive]:
main.AlterPrint()
    /home/runner/alter_print.go:62 +0x157
main.main()
    /home/runner/main.go:4 +0x20

goroutine 18 [chan send]:
main.AlterPrint.func1(0xc000074180, 0xc0000740c0, 0xc000074060)
    /home/runner/alter_print.go:27 +0x148
created by main.AlterPrint
    /home/runner/alter_print.go:14 +0xd9
exit status 2

Comment: That confirms my analysis. You should be able to fix it by executing letter<-true only if i<=28.